# How to pick random things which are conseq in table

Tags: sql-server

```
  create table TAB
  (
  id int,
  Name Char(1)
  );

  insert into TAB(ID,NAME) values(1,'A')
  insert into TAB(ID,NAME) values(1,'B')
  insert into TAB(ID,NAME) values(2,'C')
  insert into TAB(ID,NAME) values(2,'A')
  insert into TAB(ID,NAME) values(2,'B')
  insert into TAB(ID,NAME) values(3,'C')
  insert into TAB(ID,NAME) values(3,'B')
```

this is my table and values, *without using id column in where condition* i need to get c,b and 3 alone from the table

Comment: @lad2025 There is only situation where 'b' comes after 'c' ! so without using where condition on id column i need two records 'C' AND 'B'  for id 3

Comment: Is this some kind of homework or a puzzle? I can't think of any other reason to exclude the use of any tool sql provides...

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of TOP / MAX or a WHERE clause :-

```
SET ROWCOUNT 2; -- Limit the query to just 2 rows

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp; -- Ensure #tmp table doesn't already exist

SELECT ID,Name,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) as Rnk INTO #tmp FROM TAB

SELECT ID,Name FROM #tmp
```